# django : How can I get each file in formdata when I use ajax to send to the server?

Tags: python, ajax, django, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files to the server, but it receives only one file... So , I am doing something wrong. Can someone help me?!

I am using ajax in attempt to upload Multiple files

This is my view.py:

```
@csrf_protect
 def car(request):
    title = 'success'
    data = request.FILES['images[]']
    b = products(name ="car", image = data)
    b.save()
    print data
    return HttpResponse(title)
```

this is my ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = document.getElementById("images"),
                formdata = false;

            if (window.FormData) {
                formdata = new FormData();
                document.getElementById("btn").style.display = "none";
            }

            function showUploadedItem (source) {
              var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
                  li   = document.createElement("li"),
                  img  = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = source;
                li.appendChild(img);
                list.appendChild(li);
            }

            if (input.addEventListener) {
                  input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
                    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

                    document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Uploading . . ."

                    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
                      file = this.files[i];

                      if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                        if ( window.FileReader ) {
                          reader = new FileReader();
                          reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                            showUploadedItem(e.target.result);
                          };
                          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }
                        if (formdata) {
                          formdata.append("images[]", file);
                        }
                      } 
                    }
                    if (formdata) {
                        var title1 = document.getElementById("title").value
                        formdata.append('title', title1)
                        $.ajaxSetup({ 
                               beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                                   function getCookie(name) {
                                       var cookieValue = null;
                                       if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                                           var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                                           for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                                               var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                                               // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                                               if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                                                   cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                                                   break;
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }
                                       return cookieValue;
                                   }
                                   if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                                       // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                                       xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
                                   }
                               } 
                          });   
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/thunghiem/chaychoi2",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: formdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (res) {
                              document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                  }, false);
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
request.FILES.getlist('images') #or images[] as you done in javascript
```

will get a list.Then apply a for loop on it.